# completed assignment however issue with a while loop giving me wrong answer

Tags: java

So I am completed some assignments in this book I recently purchased and basically I have a set amounts of code and I have to re-arange them in-order to give me the following output:
        a-b c-d

Here is the code: [image] You can't change any of the code only re-arrange it. If you think it's impossible then show me how you would do it different using the same principles.

Here is also the same code:

```
public class carl {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 3;
    if (x > 2) {
        System.out.print("a");
    }
    while (x > 0){
    x = x - 1;
    System.out.print("-");
    }
    if (x == 2){
        System.out.print("b c");
    }
    if (x == 1){
        System.out.print("d");
        x = x - 1; 
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know what you think I did incorrectly.

I keep getting a--- doing it this way.

Comment: What do you think a loop does? Also, you can put the `if`s inside the `while`.

Comment: Well I assume it goes, my value of x is 3 first line says well if x is greater than 2 than print out a, then while x > 0 subratct 1 from x which allows my if statement to work were it says if x equals 2 then print b c which should give me a-b c at this point and my last if startment isn't true just get however it should loop through the program again so It goes back to the while statement and minus's another 1 allowing my last if statement to be true and then just simply add a d to a-b c-d and then remove the last value of x leaving it to 0.

Comment: Why would stuff outside the `while` be executed inside the while?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your surprise, I think you want

```
  int x = 3;
  if (x > 2) {
    System.out.print("a");
  }
  while (x > 0) {
    x = x - 1;
    System.out.print("-");
    // } // <-- move this
    if (x == 2) {
      System.out.print("b c");
    }
    if (x == 1) {
      System.out.print("d");
      x = x - 1;
    }
  } // <-- to here.
```

And it will print

```
a-b c-d
```

Comment: This is spot on, I didn't test it but by looking at it looks correct

Answer (score 0):

```
while (x > 0){
    x = x - 1;
    System.out.print("-");
    }
```

is changing the value of x and making it to 0 before exiting. Which is why rest of the loops are not being made true hence no output from them,

Answer (score 0):

I got it! :D It was because I had to put my closing bracket on my while statemnet at the bottom of my code. This was a great challenge, happy I got it on my own. :D